# How do I get the real file path of an image?

Tags: file-system, file-transfer

When I look at an image on my phone in the gallery app, it tells me (under details) the path is `/phone/Pictures/Messages/imagename.jpg`. My native file browser can find this image in that path. A third party file browsing app tells me it's in `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Messages/imagename.jpg`. My computer can find neither of those directories on my phone or SD card, and a search of both for the image name reveals nothing. I'd like to move the images to my phone. How do I find the real file path of this file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second one is the technically correct path. The first one, `/phone/...`, is just the Gallery app simplifying the display and telling you that the folder is in phone storage (instead of external storage).

When connected to the PC using MTP, the root folder is `/storage/emulated/0/` (you only see the contents under it), so you should be looking for the part of the path after it, which is `Pictures/Messages/imagename.jpg`.

Comment: Where is `/storage`? I just see `ZTE/phone` and `ZTE/sdcard` and neither have a storage folder inside

Comment: Did I not make it clear? `/phone` stands for `/storage/emulated/0`, and when you click inside `ZTE/phone`, you see the contents under it, so you cut this part of the path from what you got previously, leaving only `Pictures/Messages/imagename.jpg`, which is what you should go for.

Comment: There's no `Pictures` folder. It might just be hidden from my computer; that's happened to be before even though my computer shows all hidden and system files.

Comment: You possibly need to reboot the phone for it to show folders and files generated during this boot cycle. That's a downside of MTP.

Comment: No, it's still not there.

Comment: If still not working, 1) consider copying the file to an easily accessible folder (e.g. just the root folder, `/storage/emulated/0`) with the phone's file manager, and 2) use `adb pull` to pull out the file by referencing its *full* path (i.e. `/storage/emulated/0/...`). MTP is known to be wonky and hide some folders and files.

Comment: Number 1 worked, thanks. I honestly don't know why we use MTP. It seems like an extension of the Windows design philosophy, "the user is an idiot, protect the device from them at all costs"

Comment: There are explanations like the one [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/192732/android-usb-connections-explained-mtp-ptp-and-usb-mass-storage/).

Comment: @AndyYan The explanations are reasonable, yet I fail to understand why MTP's tendency to not refresh the browsable data is not considered buggy, and therefore not addressed as such.